# Bloqueo permanente o parcial (solo por un tiempo) a una red?

Tags: discusión

**(En sitio de ingles)** En mi oficina donde trabajo estamos obteniendo este error, nadie puede postear ninguna pregunta, que podemos hacer para solucionar este problema?.

```
Your post cannot be submitted at this time due to the volume of spam and abuse 
originating from your network. We apologize for any inconvenience.
```

Este bloqueo se debe a que hicimos varias preguntas o nose, pero algun dia la red estara nuevamente disponible, o se quedara bloqueada para siempre?

nota: hubiera querido postear esta pregunta en el sitio de ingles, ya que es ahi el problema que tenemos, pero no pude publicarlo porque no tengo 5 puntos de reputacion.

Les agradesco mucho su ayuda!!!

Comment: SI el problema es en el sitio en inglés y consideras que es incorrecto entonces deberias escribirlo a traves de https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact

Answer (score 6):

El problema es que la IP desde donde estas conectado a la red, fue marcada como abusiva por la propia red.

Por favor mira [¿Por qué mi publicación ha sido bloqueada debido a 'spam y abuso desde mi red’?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/abuse-block).

Cada uno de estos casos se detecta automáticamente, y los bloqueos también son automáticos.

Si opinas que esto es incorrecto, y tienes pruebas de ello, por favor déjanos un mensaje para que podamos elevarlo a quienes corresponda.

Comment: maso menos cuanto tiempo durara esta penalizacion ?